# Trying to create forum pager and order the results at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, pager

When the Mysql queries get more complicated ... i am done ...

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM posts
    WHERE parrentid = :parrentid
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT :resultsofthispage,:maxresultsperpage
");
$stmt->execute([
    ':parrentid'         => $the_input_id,
    ':resultsofthispage' => $this_page_first_result,
    ':maxresultsperpage' => $results_per_page
]);
```

I am trying to make my forum page where the user opens up a category/topic and he gets results sorted by date "ORDER BY date DESC". After this i added "LIMIT :resultsofthispage,:maxresultsperpage" for the category/topic pager. Did i build my code in a wrong way?

Comment: Looks good. Does it work?

Comment: By the way, please escape special characters, this page will be hacked by cybercriminals using sql injection in no time.

Comment: What do you by saying escape special characters? Not only that i am using prepared statements, but i also have check if the input is numberic, if it is not, it redirects the user back to the index.

Comment: I tested that same code in a different way and it works, this code is the only thing that causes me problem in my website.

Comment: Well paul, i actually thought you edited the code in a way in which will work. Thanks for the edit but still, what's the point if the question looks good if nobody will answer it.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the only one who don't like to scroll the code vertically. In first instance I did it for myself, so I can actually read and understand it. However - for me, this part of code seems to be perfectly fine. So if you have any problem, it must (probably) be outsite of what you have posted.

Comment: YEAH, it actually is. My code is really long and turns out i made 2 BIG mistakes on very important places. I thought that i am writing the sql code wrong. Anyway, thank you for your time. And my apology.

Comment: Nope... beside the 2 BIG mistakes that i made, there is really problem in the code i just posted. The problem is that i can't use parameters in the LIMIT command, actually i can but it's complicated... i am reading atm how to solve this. I am posting this comment in order to prevent someone who needs help to finds my post and think that the code is written correctly.